# Executing this.function on React Native/Router Flux with forwardRef

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am actually updating an app that's contains this code:

routes.js

```
<Scene key='events' component={Events} title='Brief'/>
```

Events/index.js

```
static onEnter() {
    Actions.refs.events.getWrappedInstance().refreshScene()
}

refreshScene = () => {
    this.setState({any: true})
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
{
    ...
}, null, {withRef: true})(Events)
```

But now, the newest version of router flux don't accept anymore withRef. You must replace by forwardRef.

So,

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps,
{
    ...
}, null, {forwardRef: true})(Events)
```

will not allow Actions.refs.events.getWrappedInstance().refreshScene() anymore. And I can't make my refreshScene() works again.

Any clue about how to solve the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

react-native-router-flux seems to have removed `Actions.refs` functionality since version 4.0.0

[Comment on the issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2958#issuecomment-376077282) from one of the contributors suggests:

> - Either use a HOC
> - Either use Redux to pass the same method in your components
> - Either use your method as a prop and doing the trick in this way

[Here is the changelog](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/1848731505677a264460a21d207e9377bdf653f0/CHANGELOG.md#400-beta31-2018-05-14)